# Cast Close & Reopen Votes Privilege awarded at less than 3k rep

Tags: support, privileges

The Privilege for casting close and reopen votes was awarded to me when I was 1 point shy of 3,000. Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Maybe an upvote that got reversed?

Comment: Or you downvoted an answer,  a post of yours was downvoted, a post you gained rep on was deleted, or any number of other actions that can cause you to lose rep.

Comment: Can you actually review them right now (at 2999)?  If not, it's probably as rene suggests, and the notification got sent while you were momentarily at 3k.

Comment: I just got the Privilege today and I haven't had any activity in a few days if that helps? The last rep change was MArch 4th

Comment: @MarkC. You don't need to have performed any activities recently in order to have earned rep today, or to have since lost some of it.  Your posts can be voted on (among other actions) to increase and decrease your rep without you doing anything.

Comment: Oh so you're saying if someone upvoted something of mine and put me >= 3k and then reversed their upvote, I still get the privilege?

Comment: @MarkC. only temporarily.  You just get the notification, but then lose the privilege when it's reversed and you drop back under 3k.

Comment: Alrighty. We can just assume one of these took place. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

There's a 0 today (March 10th) entry for [your rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2679750/mark-c?tab=reputation) with the note

> There were no net reputation changes on this day

That indicates some action was performed and reversed e.g. an upvote followed by an unupvote, or an accept followed by an unaccept.

So you had the privilege for a while, you got the notification then somebody changed their mind and now you don't.

Comment: Yep, the "_There were no net reputation changes on this day_" message suggests this is the case.

Comment: Note that rep lost from post deletions wouldn't show up there for you, nor would the user downvoting any posts, or certain other activities, so it's not *necessarily* an unupvote.

Comment: @Servy my list of examples is certainly not exhaustive.

Comment: still have that issue http://i.stack.imgur.com/mqhSz.png